# Converting a php array to a unicode json

Tags: php, json

I need to convert a dynamic array to the following format. I am only posting a sample

```
{u'v2':{0:u'No',1:u'Yes'}, u'v3':{1:u'Maybe',3:u'Almost'}}
```

This is what I did:

```
$valLabels = array();
 $valLabelTemp1 = array();
 $valLabelTemp2 = array();

 $valLabelTemp1['v2'][0] = 'No';
 $valLabelTemp1['v2'][1] = 'Yes';
 $valLabels = $valLabelTemp1; 

 $valLabelTemp2['v3'][0] = 'Maybe';
 $valLabelTemp2['v3'][1] = 'Almost';
 $valLabels = $valLabelTemp2;
```

When I write the above in a text file:

> fwrite($fh,json_encode($valLabels) . "\n");

I get the following output:

```
{"v2":["No","Yes"],"v3":["Maybe","Almost"]}
```

I dun want the above format. Plus I need to affix the 'U' to represent unicode. I am not sure how can I do to the format. Advance thanks.

Comment: Json doesn't have a `u` prefix for strings (that's specific to python afaik), why do you need that?

Comment: RC, Spot on!!!...I need it to run it on the python script for spss conversion.

Comment: python understand standard json (see `json` module), no `u` needed.

Comment: Okie. How do I do it in php with the following data structure than?{'v2':{0:u'No',1:u'Yes'}, 'v3':{1:'Maybe',3:'Almost'}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php

$valLabels = array(
  'v2' => array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'), 
  'v3' => array('1' => 'Maybe','3' => 'Almost')
);

echo json_encode($valLabels);
```

output:

```
{"v2":{"1":"Yes","0":"No"},"v3":{"1":"Maybe","3":"Almost"}}
```

**NB: we need to revert (this doesn't matter in the json result) the `v2` data [otherwise](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php#50115) php does some kind of smart type convertion and you loose indices.**

[Demo](https://ideone.com/8MHIQN)

Comment: First of all, I would like to Thank you for your quick response. What I need is the key is in integers and not string. In your case the key for 0 is "0" whereas the one I need is 0.

Comment: Well done with the reverting of `v2`. I was just fiddling with this and realised that `v2` was always output as an array and not as an object. Even if I set the indices as strings... Sometimes I so dislike PHP :-D

Comment: @Havelock, I agree 100% here, this type conversion is a pain and somehow stupid (changing value order changes behavior?!)

Comment: Okie. let me look at it and will mark it solved soon. Thank you